# Proof of combinatorial identity with two parameters $p$ and $q$

Tags: combinatorics

What would be an approach to prove the following identity for $p,q$ positive integers:

$$\sum \limits_{k=0}^q \frac{1}{2^{p+k}} \binom{p+k}{k} + \sum \limits_{k=0}^p \frac{1}{2^{q+k}} \binom{q+k}{k} = 2$$

Thanks for any ideas, it's taken from a french contest (concours général 1985).

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: A humorous combinatorial proof can be found at https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h1189732p5810557 (Q&A by RadioActive, #73)